# How to prevent Android Telnet Client Sessions from dropping

Tags: android, client, telnet

I am an employee at packing and distribution warehouse. We currently use an open-source Android telnet server and client, but we are getting frustrated because anytime we switch to a different app on our Android scanning devices, our telnet session drops. We have tried every way we know how and are unable to keep the sessions running while we do our other tasks on the same device.

Two questions:
1. Is there coding to keep the telnet sessions from constantly dropping, or to stay running in the background at all times?

2. Or - is there another Android telnet Client or Server that already functions as I am requesting?

Thanks for any insight.

- K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K,

Newer Android versions tend to put apps to "sleep" to conserve resources when they are not on the screen (in the background), this will break a telnet or ssh connection. There may be a setting in the client to force the connection to stay awake, but I do not know what you are using.

I have tested and used GSW ConnectBot on Android Nougat, Oreo and Pie and have not had the "sleep" issue. I am able to move from app to app without dropping my connections.

You can tale a look at this Android Telnet client at https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/connectbot-client-android

Sam